# Invalid pipeline option

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

Trying to set define a pipeline before using pyspark

```
filter_users="[{'$and': [{'user': {'$in': ['player','npc']}}]}]"
spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource"). \
        option("spark.mongodb.input.uri", 'data_users'). \
        option('pipeline',filter_users).load()
```

Returns the error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException:requirement failed: Invalid Aggregation map Map(uri -> mongodb://localhost:27017/local.pii_val?readPreference=primaryPreferred, pipeline -> ["[{$and: [{\'user\': {\'$in\': [\'player\',\'npc\']}}]}]"]):
```

Also tried to remove then '' between the operators and or in.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not an aggregation pipeline. see the doc [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/)

You have to put your query in a `$match` object

```
filter_users="[{'$match: {'$and': [{'user': {'$in': ['player','npc']}}]}}]"
```